# Can I switch to Windows cmd in Ubuntu for Windows (WSL)?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL. I can start and exit the Ubuntu command-line with `ubuntu` or `exit` respectively, but I also want to run `cmd` commands there.

How can I start `cmd.exe` from within the WSL terminal?

Comment: I use my ubuntu command line for nearly all things, sometimes i need to run a windows command in the directory where i am working,  i would like to switch to the windows console for a moment instead of starting a new and seperate windows terminal. But an explenation of how to use windows cmd.exe commands within ubuntu would be usefull too

Comment: @dessert This answer is not a duplicate of that question. The question that you linked to is about how to start a Windows executable in **Ubuntu**. This question however is about how to start a Windows executable in **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)** ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux ).

Comment: Questions relating to Windows Subsystem for Linux, the compatibility layer developed by Canonical and Microsoft to run Ubuntu programs natively in newer versions of Windows, are on topic at Ask Ubuntu. [`wsl` tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/wsl/info) at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @dessert Edited the question and added the `wsl` tag. I hope this edit will be sufficient to scare off predatory downvoters and reviewers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within a Bash/WSL console you can invoke Windows executables by specifying the (correctly-cased) name of the executable, including its .exe extension (example: `notepad.exe [filename]`). To start a new cmd shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program type:

```
cmd.exe
```

Comment: and you dont need an emulator like WINE or so?

Comment: In Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you don't need Wine. Reference: [Interop between Windows and Bash](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/)

Comment: @dessert Okay, i misunderstood the question, the questioner is on Windows the whole time. Sorry, but does this question not belong in some Windows forum.?

Comment: Questions relating to Windows Subsystem for Linux, the compatibility layer developed by Canonical and Microsoft to run Ubuntu programs natively in newer versions of Windows, are on topic at Ask Ubuntu. [`wsl` tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/wsl/info) at Ask Ubuntu.